# Framebreaker detection

Tags: javascript, html, frame

I need some way to detect if site from some URL is framebreaker or not. I mean that **Framebreaker** - site which brake frame structure if it loaded in a frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you're asking is 'how do I prevent my web page from being viewed in a frame?' then here's the [best solution currently known](http://seclab.stanford.edu/websec/framebusting/framebust.pdf):

Use CSS to set the page's body to not display:

```
<style>
  body { display : none ; }
</style>
```

Then only display the page if it's not in a frame:

```
<script>
  if (self == top) {
    //Not in a frame
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    //In a frame. Redirect to the real page.
    top.location = self.location;
  }
</script>
```

Put the style in the <head> and the script in the <body>.

If you just wanted to detect if the page is being framed, but not do anything about it, all you need is the following javascript:

```
<script>
  if(self == top) {
    alert("Not in a frame");
  } else {
    alert("In a frame");
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you've tagged this as php, only javascript can do this...

```
if (top !== window) {
    top.location.href = '/url/';
}
```

Comment: I need to detect if site is Framebreaker then alert about that. Tag removed, thanks.

Comment: That's a framebreaker script not a prevention

Comment: And how can I prevent framebreaker?

Comment: Yu already marked this question / answer relation as solved Ôo